# Welcome file with java config in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot mainly to serve some static content with some basic additional features.

Recently I somehow managed to map default / view to my index.html in the following way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class WebStarter extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/app/shared/**").addResourceLocations("classpath:/www/app/shared/");
    }


    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/").setViewName("index.html");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        run(WebStarter.class, args);
    }
}
```

Now I am not able to solve that, and I cannot understand why. I am just getting the following exception:

`javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'index.html' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'`

Maybe it is somehow linked with Spring Boot version, because I was changing it recently. Or is there any other way how to map default view?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I solved it. Not sure if coreect, but at least it works. Just added my own resource resolver and registered it.

```
    @Override
public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
  registry.addResourceHandler("/").addResourceLocations("classpath:/www/").resourceChain(true).addResolver(new CustomResourceResolver("/", "/index.html"));
}
```

And the resolver:

```
public class CustomResourceResolver implements ResourceResolver {

private String requestPath;

private String resource;

public CustomResourceResolver(String requestPath, String resource) {
    this.requestPath = requestPath;
    this.resource = resource;
}

@Override
public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {

    if (!this.requestPath.equals(requestPath)) {
        return null;
    }

    try {

        for (Resource location : locations) {
            File file = new File(location.getFile(), resource);
            if (file.exists()) {
                return new FileSystemResource(file);
            }
        }

        return null;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}

@Override
public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
    return null;
}
```